# Using the same Fragment in an Endless ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Looking for a bit of insight. I have a list of forum threads coming from an API which the user clicks on and it loads up a fragment with the posts in that thread.

What I want the user to do is be able to swipe between each thread while they're looking into it. Like how Gmail does it when the user looks at each email by swiping through.

I'm happy to answer any more questions. I couldn't find anything on here specific to what I'm looking for but I may be wrong.

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question?

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I use the same fragment for a viewpager but change an ID for the api call ?

Comment: So you want to re use the same fragment but with different data?

Comment: @RavjitSinghUppal yes, that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: "how can I use the same fragment for a viewpager" -- do you mean the same fragment *class* or the same fragment *instance*? The latter is not possible, as `ViewPager` needs a minimum of three instances. If you mean the same fragment class, most `ViewPager` examples show that, so it is unclear what specific problem you are encountering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood your question properly, this should be the solution.

Lets say the fragment that displays the thread is called **ThreadFragment**.
You can have an arraylist of this fragments in your FragmentPagerAdapter class.

```
private ArrayList<ThreadFragment> threadFragments = new ArrayList<>(size)
```

Where size is the number of threads you have. Create 'size' fragments in a loop and and it to the array list.

```
for(all the threads) {
    threadFragments.add(new ThreadFragment(data from your api));
}
```

implement the other functions of the FragmentPagerAdapter as follow:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
   return threadFragments.size();
}

@Override 
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    return threadFragments.get(pos);
}
```

Suggestions for you to try: Instead of passing parameter in the Fragment's constructor, try to use Bundle. You can also have an abstract method in the fragment to get the data, and implement it in the FragmentPagerAdapter when you create the fragment.

Comment: this would fail if you try to jump from page 1 to page 6 directly on a button click or an event.